# How long does the User Token/Client last with Box Platform API?

Tags: box-api, box

I'm developing a server-side application to upload files to Box. I'm using the Box .NET SDK, using JWT for authentication.

Here's how I set up my Box stuff:

```
var boxConfig = new BoxConfig(clientId, clientSecret, enterpriseId, jwtPrivateKey, jwtPrivateKeyPassword, jwtPublicKeyId);
var boxJwt = new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig);

var userToken = boxJwt.UserToken(boxAppUserId);
var userClient = boxJwt.UserClient(userToken, boxAppUserId);
```

Then I use the UserClient object to upload a file to Box once a day.

My question is: Will that UserClient or UserToken ever expire? I want to know if I should get a new UserToken and instantiate a UserClient every time I need to use it, or if I could initialize all these things just once when my application starts up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token will expire after roughly one hour. The client is designed to [fetch a new user/admin token as necessary](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/blob/master/Box.V2.JWTAuth/JWTAuthRepository.cs#L36-L53) so you shouldn't need to worry about it after the client is initially created. You might even try specifying a blank token when initializing the client and let the re-authentication logic handle things from the beginning:

```
var userClient = boxJwt.UserClient("", boxAppUserId);
```